# Constructor vs refreshing/setting properties

Tags: .net, vb.net

Is there any advantage to calling a method to re-initialize a classes properties vs creating a new object?  I'm working on an application that does that a lot, and am considering refactoring it to eliminate these calls.

The original developers were more familiar with VB6, so it could be a habit that they brought over.

Is there something I'm missing that would make this a good idea?

EDIT: The classes are lightweight, basically data classes with a dozen or so primitive properties and this refresh method.

Comment: I would not eliminate the calls. See answer from Bradley +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an advantage in some high performance situations.

.NET relies on the garbage collector to clean up variables as they go out of scope, so constantly creating instances and throwing them away will require more frequent garbage collection, which eats CPU and can pause your threads in some situations.

If your objects take a lot of resources to instantiate then you will also benefit from reusing the objects instead of creating new ones.  There is actually a pattern called "Pooling" that allocates a pool of objects and draws instances from the pool, initializing them as needed, and returning them to the pool when you are finished with them.  This is the same pattern that things like the ThreadPool and SSQL Connection Pooling use to manage "heavy" resources.  It can significantly help performance on smaller objects too in some situations where many objects would normally be created and go out of scope quickly.

Comment: I thought that the CLR was a bit smarter than that, and that local objects were easily GC'd? But I can't find the article I was thinking of...anyway, I don't think this a likely reason why this pattern was usedas there would be at most a few thousand extra references over the course of a day (i.e. plenty of time for GC to get rid of them)

Comment: Local variables that are value types are cleanup very easily because they are stack based.  When a stack frame is popped all the values on it are cleaned up.  Reference types are managed by garbage collector and their memory is only reclaimed when it runs.  You are right that threads and sql connection are not pooled due to garbage collection, they are pooled because they area heavy objects that take a lot of work to instantiate.It all comes down to your access patterns and instantiation costs as to whether pooling will benefit you.

Comment: Right, but I thought there was static analysis being done that allowed local variables (reference types) to be cleaned up quickly and easily for either vb or c# (similiar to what can be done with managed c++ where you can have the semantics of having created a ref typs on the stack).